# ToC at the beginning of each section do now show all sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, parts

In beamer,I used the following code to show the ToC at two pages.
One page was not enough because it shows all its subsections.
I didn't use 'allowframebreaks' because it breaks at 'random' location rather than appropriately divide sections.

```
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[part=1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}
```

I also show ToC at the beginning of each section with other sections shaded.

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=hide]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Here, I want to show 'all' sections because I hided all subsections so there's enough space.

The problem is that the ToC at the beginning of each section only shows part 1 or part 2. How can I display all sections at each section with the initial ToC divided into two slides?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself:

\AtBeginSection part remain unchanged.

I removed \part{1} and \part{2} in the main text contents and then replaced \tableofcontents[part=1] and \tableofcontents[part=2] by \tableofcontents[section=1-3] and \tableofcontents[section=4-6]

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer.