# How to list Beamer TOC's all sections without part separation?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, parts

I want list all sections without part separation in the main table of contents. 
I did not find relevant threads, similar one [How to collect all parts in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79388/13173) 
Code where the main *Table of Contents* is only about the first `\part{}` in Fig. 1, while wanted output - all sections without part separation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346486/13173
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\insertsection-#1}
}
{\end{frame}}
% fragile only if code
% allowframebreaks not by default 

\begin{document} 
\title{Sensory system. Primary sensory modalities. Cortical modalities. Kinds of sensory disturbances. Spinal cord disorders. Spinal cord transverse and partial lesion. Cauda equina damage.}
\author{Leo}

% TODO Print TOC of all parts here

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115891/13173
\AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections, pausesections]
\end{frame}}

\AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}}

% not complete answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353064/13173

\section{Cortical modalities 1}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 2}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 3}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\part{}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 4}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\section{Cortical modalities 5}
\begin{slide}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Expected output: table of contents of sections 1-5 in a list without separating them by parts

- Not Part 1 a b c, Part 2 d e
- Wanted: a b c d e

OS: Debian 8.7
TeXLive: 2016

Comment: The OS information is rather irrelevant here! There's no need to specify it in each question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As said in previous answers to your questions, don't use `\usepackage{hyperref}` in a beamer document.

Loop over the different parts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{part}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}{%
    \vskip-0.4cm
    \tableofcontents[part=\x]%
}%
\end{frame}


\section{Cortical modalities 1}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 2}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 3}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\part{}
\section{Cortical modalities 4}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 5}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\part{}
\section{Cortical modalities 6}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\section{Cortical modalities 7}
\begin{frame}{basics} 
    More refined aspects of sensation ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(the value `\vskip-0.4cm` is guessed by eye, maybe it needs some more fine tuning)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Beamer already loads hyperref. Loading it again is a) useless and b) poses the risk to cause an option clash.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 To get the total number of part, you can use the `totcount` package.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308343/how-to-create-mini-sections-mini-subsections-and-mini-frames-in-beamer-presenta/313579#313579 how the total number of sections is determined. You can do the same for parts.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  I don't understand what  you mean by "But to which variable do you save the count?". But please see my edited answer.